# Appium: iOS Getting UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: ios, appium-ios

Platform compatibility :

```
Mac OS X 10.10 or higher, 10.11.1 recommended **[Using 10.10.5]**

XCode >= 6.0, 7.1.1 recommended **[Using 7]**

Apple Developer Tools (iPhone simulator SDK, command line tools) 

Appium Server **[Using v1.5.3]**

Node.js **[Using V4.5.0]**
```

Don't actually know which is the perfect combination of all the SDK/requirements for configuring the Appium in MAC system.

And getting an error in Appium logcat:
Unable to load node configuration file to register with grid.

My code is

```
@BeforeTest
public void preSetup() throws MalformedURLException{

    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    File f=new File("/Users/nandini/Documents/AppiumWorkSpace/One20Automation/app/One20.app");

    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 6");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9.0");

    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("udid", "E1791000-5BC8-4741-A1AC-416FDEEB3048");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, "MAC");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Safari");
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, f.getAbsolutePath());

    driver=new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

Note: Actually app is getting installed but not lunching the app and further work.Also by code simulator is appearing in screen, but after sometimes automatically closing it.

Please suggest.

Comment: first thing- for simulator udid can't be used in capabilities, it's only for real devices. second- the way udid is passed its wrong. third- you cannot specify browser and app both at same time in capabilities. fourth-can you share your logs for more clarity on error you are facing